# Text not wrapping around image in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, text, word-wrap

I am trying to add a success onto a page on our website: https://www.knowsleycollege.ac.uk/results-day-2021-successes/ and have the image appear on the right, and the text wrapping around it.

However, it seems to align to the right, but then not all the text wraps around it. I have tried adjusting the CSS, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

How can this be solved?

Comment: Is it possible that the "Carl said..." sentence is starting as a new paragraph? Try deleting the space between the previous sentence and that sentence so they are a single line. Then use CTRL+ENTER instead of ENTER so it doesn't create a new paragraph. I can be completely wrong too.

Comment: Gave your suggestion a go, but unfortunately, it does the same.

Comment: When you say "I have tried adjusting the CSS, but nothing seems to work.", please include the code snippet you've tried in your question, both your html structure and css rules, so that we could take a look at them and hopefully debug them for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<p>` tag has "clear:both" property set. Due to this the text is not wrapping adjacent to the image. see the screenshot for reference.
Removing this "clear" property will work for you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to the GENERAL `clear: both;` setting for `p` tags of your theme. You could erase that in your stylesheet, but that might affect a lot of other pages.

Or you add a `style="clear:none"` attribute to those `p` tags which follow the image in the "text" (actually code) mode of the editor, like

```
<p style="clear:none"> ...your text ... </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to ensure the paragraph clear property is set to none.